# prove that for every 3 natural numbers x,y,z

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Prove that for every three natural numbers x, y and z strictly greater than 1, there is some natural number larger than x, y, and z that is not divisible by x, y or z.

I am studying for a university discrete math exam and on our sample midterm is this question.

The solution provided is:

Since x, y, and z are natural numbers greater than 1, the number (xyz+1) is not divisible by either x, y or z, as xyz is a multiple of all of the three numbers, and (xyz+1)≡ 1(mod x), (xyz+1)≡ 1(mod y) and (xyz+1)≡ 1(mod z). Thus, we have proved by constructive proof that there exists at least one number greater than x, y, and z, which is not divisible by either of the three.

Can someone help me understand this? I don't understand where all the (xyz+1)≡ 1(mod x), (xyz+1)≡ 1(mod y) and (xyz+1)≡ 1(mod z) came from or how he got there. Cannot go to office hours either, exam is on monday.

I understand the concept of modulo and congruency, what am I missing?

Comment: The concept of "congruency" is that $a\equiv b\pmod n$ if $\frac1n(a-b)$ is an integer.

Comment: You say you understand modulo and congruency, but you don't understand why $xyz+1 \equiv 1 \pmod x$ when $x$ is a natural number greater than $1$?

Comment: What's the first sentence you don't understand?

Comment: Start from "(xyz+1) is not divisible by either x, y or z".

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Thank you, I needed that. The professor does not go over a lot of stuff that is on the exams. It's a top university but the average score on the midterms is 55%... I've only missed lecture once but there is still so much vital information that is still in the dark

Comment: $n \equiv b \pmod{a} \;\;[meaning \;numbers \;\;n=a.t+b]$
$n \equiv 1 \pmod{4} \;\;[meaning \;numbers \;\;n=4t+1]$ where $t$ is any natural number starting with 0.

Answer (score 1):

Skiping all that fancy mod stuff is easier.
x divides xyz.
If x divides xyz + 1, then x divides xyz+1 - xyz = 1.
Likewise for y and z but none of them are 1.